# How to maintain type inference when mapping an object of function creators to an object of created functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**TLDR:** I'm trying to create a mapper function that "applies" an HttpClient to function creators, and maintains the typing information of the created functions. Typing example of the input/output:

```
retrieveAge: (id: string) => (client: HttpClient) => number;
modifyName: (id: string, newName: string) => (client: HttpClient) => void;
```

->

```
retrieveAge: (id: string) => number;
modifyName: (id: string, name: string) => void;
```

The result is the created functions (no longer needing to be called with an HttpClient).

**Context/Attempt**

I'm setting up a library of API method calls to get/post data. I want to expose methods that allow consumers to pass in their own "http client", but also expose the same methods that already have a default http client "attached". I'm wanting to make sure both versions of the exported methods maintain typing information.

The approach I'm attempting (and maybe this is not the best way) is to make the retrieve/update methods function creators that you can call with the http client to prime them with the client you wish to use (default, or otherwise).

I have a semi-working solution, but it only works if all the methods follow the exact interface. Otherwise, it complains about the call signature of methods in the passed in object not matching. For example, it complains that type number from retrieveAge is not assignable to type Name from retrieveName.

```
 Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Name'.
```

If I only have one method in my methods object, it works fine.

I've reproduced the issue with bare JS and TS below. At the bottom, you can see me manually create the object I want the "applyClient" function to create, and the resulting types.
Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYoN4ChkHIzBQDOY6WAXMuVKAOYA0%20hANnOZRDXY7gF9cYAJ4AHFAEEGKALzIQAVwwAjaAG5cuUJFiIUACTBgxAYTbAI4ZHkLIZYADwAVAHwAKKBFIB7RVCReMHoQBgBKGmcWOzEfchcPL19-QNpgxiZkMTgRNh84ABNIiOQANx9gAsEtXAB6WqI4AGsUACICiHhFNjBW5AQLKzBcBB8QcmQOrp7zS3AaIxNZoeR5W0IHGhhFEAQwYDGE9zDsLzB-EGQAcgBGACYAZivkTmQdppAfAHdL1%20cBaKEWLkLY7PYHEBHbK5fJFZDOE7IIRCLSjcZgZBYMAACx8BVIqxsrAIZ3oEFKEGkPGQ7kqQRC4VWrhpAzmYAWxjMg3AYSZ-W5YAAdA5HNwPAADECYCC1AAk2EqAnFYUBJIg6XJEG4NFpcL4oV5smZ7lZQw5SwFhuZpvAwvVjipErgMjlCoKSpVxMxeOAMBE2ppdLSDMyIAgXwD%20sZRpZAvNXLZVv5bMFwKcUYlUqwrsV4tD4e4YWqdQAVCX4QBNAAKAFEAMr4cv9MYTLG4-E0dZ2NUailUnVBqNJk1x5CLBNDJNKVQaL12UmWCkB3X0xjDm3ssec5Y8vncTTdwgYH1%205eD9KhfMR6Wrg18kds%20M7sBJ8qVA%20EITIEu1LRtvGkIKC6alS7hXA8AAsUF3FcYTuFMcDdGAz5hJo-74kB6pkku0pgZB0GwfBnSITMlpoeq7aAceBS%20v6uHgVBEEwZkVwAFI%20Nilx1hgwA4oRCFIShmjCOIhicgAshReIuJkADSzLyO4grKXAUAMKQkQANoALrrqO44oXysmaKIEjIJJOLSVEyDyYSSkqWpGnwjpSbGVo2y7PsYwvGIYhsCIz4yTZHg%20CoABWNAAEoQKMUAFI4UaZOOFntkF8muJkG5PpaXbNuimJwL5EAFAA8uFMWbtFsXxS0Ig%20DAyCmRA9XIKFYWZClVlya4Ck2AIH4EDAPhQDSbDqsgmm1Zk6Haa1DVlWFFWCkMZKkO4bVhLyuV2BghUSKV5V7JNEAiLNinKYKqnqUm6H2ZdjlwRuqFel%20hBnBcBVFQdi17JoKJohMYZfJ1%20KEnt-nPu46GkJkAmkYmwlAyDgHAX2Mh4YxMHPUjUkYajWr0fhTGwZoOOWRh1G0dwGMESx7Gccg3G8diJNaPU8LYsABJc412IoG1FW1KZjAEjicAYgAksgXyvLiYiMLzKDgwFAqYrj0t%20GwBRZFAeKKIEdQNADGJohSUCQAUyOEng7Pzlhi6UjIA56he0bMtDmG9o7EC6o9losLbb325qZ4uwyN24yjwc4VgvsPpOAcNDtJ50dQgZhxkCg3sGa58h7lOnrhlShtKfuJobSKluWzjVvWjYEMbeVmxbyOdnOQde-26e3m7CjKGoUADd2%20Ohz3Sb7u3BAF6n1Irjnl5Z2nQ58m%20BR-Y2v7s84nPcwSuJfIravkwSXya9raj9HAbBjdrcAwLoyDYnApQKziKAbsgrTg5YBR9FfXiFBEFQCuptoAt0jp7bC3sabE2euzUB5tirI0gQ7amDECJwKNmMZuSCIHTzQUTZi1x6ZcR4nxVCQA) with the same code.

```
interface Name {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}
type Age = number;

interface HttpClient {
    get<T>(resource: string): T,
    post<T>(resource: string, payload: T): void
}


// fake "default" client
const defaultClient: HttpClient = {
    get: function<T>(){return '123' as unknown as T},
    post: function<T>(payload: T){ }
}


const methods = {
    retrieveAge: (id: string) => (client: HttpClient) => client.get<Name>(`name/${id}`),
    retrieveName: (id: string) => (client: HttpClient) => client.get<Age>(`age/${id}`),
    modifyName: (id: string, newName: string) => (client: HttpClient) => client.post<string>(`name/${id}`, newName)
}

/** TYPES
 *  const methods: {
        retrieveAge: (id: string) => (client: HttpClient) => number;
        retrieveName: (id: string) => (client: HttpClient) => Name;
        modifyName: (id: string, newName: string) => (client: HttpClient) => void;
    }
 */

methods.retrieveAge('34442')(defaultClient);
methods.retrieveName('34442')(defaultClient);
methods.modifyName('34442', 'John Smith')(defaultClient);

type HttpMethod<T, K> = (...args: T[]) => (client: HttpClient) => K;
type Method<T, K> = (...args: T[]) => K;

function applyClient<T, K>(obj: Record<string, HttpMethod<T, K>>, client: HttpClient){
    const mappedObject: Record<keyof typeof obj, Method<T, K>> = {};
    for (let [key, method] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        mappedObject[key] = (...args) => method(...args)(client);
    }
    return mappedObject;
}

const newMethods = applyClient(methods, defaultClient);

newMethods.retrieveAge('34442');
newMethods.retrieveName('34442');
newMethods.modifyName('34442', 'John Smith');

// This is the object/typings that I was hoping the applyClient method would produce:
// const convertedMethods = {
//     retrieveAge: (id: string) => methods.retrieveAge(id)(client),
//     retrieveName: (id: string) => methods.retrieveName(id)(client),
//     modifyName: (id: string, name: string) => methods.modifyName(id, name)(client)
// }
/** TYPES
 *  const convertedMethods: {
        retrieveAge: (id: string) => number;
        retrieveName: (id: string) => Name;
        modifyName: (id: string, name: string) => void;
}
 */
// This is how the methods would be called after having the client "applied" already:
// convertedMethods.retrieveAge('34442');
// convertedMethods.retrieveName('34442');
// convertedMethods.modifyName('34442', 'John Smith');
```

Comment: You might want to use the built-in `ReturnType` type utility: `ReturnType<() => number>` resolves to `number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would like to achieve is possible thanks to mapped types in TypeScript.

I have provided some working code that works as you would expect, except it leverages Axios instead of your custom HTTPClient. I have included comments in the code that should explain everything in detail. You can jump to the bottom of the answer to see example usage and results and then return to the beginning for the implementation details. The original return type and argument type information is successfully preserved.

First, the type definitions of the outer and inner functions, argument types for the outer function, as well as some return type definitions:

```
// Requestor is the inner function, which expects to retrieve an axios instance and return some value of some type
type Requestor<R> = (axios: AxiosInstance) => R;

/* 
Creator is the outer function, which returns a Requestor.
Note the two generic arguments that Creator takes: Arguments and R.
Arguments: provides typing for the arguments of the Creator (examples below).
R: The return type of the Creator, which is also the return type of the inner Requestor function
These two generic arguments maximize reusability of the Creator type.
*/
type Creator<Arguments extends [...args: any], R> = (...args: Arguments) => Requestor<R>;


/* 
GetRequestArgs is an example of what could be passed to an axios.get() call.
This type defines an arguments list of length 1. The argument name is 'config' and its type is AxiosRequestConfig
Note: this example assumes that the data property of the AxiosRequestConfig is not utilized.
*/
type GetRequestArgs = [config?: AxiosRequestConfig];

/* 
DataRequestArgs is a compound Arguments type definition. The first argument has name 'data' 
and can have any type you'd like (hence the generic argument 'D'). The second argument.

NOTE: The name 'getRequestArgs' can be thought of as a placeholder. ...getRequestArgs expands
the GetRequestArgs Arguments definition into this new definition. Therefore, the resulting 
arguments definition is actually: data: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig
*/
type DataRequestArgs<D> = [data: D, ...getRequestArgs: GetRequestArgs];

/*
Another example of a compound Arguments definition. The result of this definition is:
customArg: string, otherArg: number, data: D, config: AxiosRequestConfig

See above note regarding argument expansion.
*/
type CustomArgs<D> = [customArg: string, otherArg: number, ...dataArgs: DataRequestArgs<D>];

// some simple return type definitions
type FirstReturnType = {value: string};
type SecondReturnType = {value: string, errorCode: number};
```

Next, the "magic" Type definition that defines the object that is the result of applying the default Axios instance:

```
/*
The magic. This type defines the new object that is the result of iterating over an object whose values
are Creators and applying an axios instance to each of them.

Note: line breaks added in order to easily add explanatory comments. The actual type definition
could be defined in a single line.
*/

// T here is the mapping described above
type Mapped<T> = {
    // Set constrains on the keys of the new object. We want the keys of the original mapping to be preserved.
    [K in keyof T]
    
    // anything after this colon marks the start of the type definition of our new object.
    : 
    
    // The beginning of a ternary expression. T[K] represents a Creator since T is our original mapping
    // and K represents a key of the aforementioned mapping. Here, we check if the result of accessing our
    // mapping using key K results in something that can be invoked.
    T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? 

    // The truthy part of the ternary expression. Here, we are certain that T[K] can be invoked.
    // Therefore, the value of our new object at each key K will be the function definition seen below.

    // ...args: Parameters<T[K] allows us to keep the typing of the arguments of each Creator in our original mapping.

    // ReturnType<ReturnType<T[K]>> allows us to keep the typing of the Requestor returned by each Creator.
    (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T[K]>> 
    
    // T[K] was not actually something that can be invoked, oh well.
    : never
};
```

Next, the function that applies the default Axios instance:

```
/*
Function that iterates over an object whose values are Creators and applies an axios instance to each of them.

The result of this function is a new object that has the keys of the original mapping. The values of the new object
are functions that maintain the same Arguments typing information of the original Creators, but with a default
axios instance applied. The return type information of the original Creators is also maintained.
*/
function prepCreators<T>(creators: T): Mapped<T>{

    let returnValue = {};

    for(let [name, creator] of Object.entries(creators)){
        returnValue[name] = (…args: any) => creator(…args)(axios);
    }

    return returnValue as Mapped<T>;
}
```

Next, some sample Creator definitions:

```
/*
First example of a Creator definition. This creator is expected to return a Promise of type FirstReturnType.

Note how we do not have to provide typing information for the config argument. The typing information has
already been provided by the GetRequestArgs type. Therefore, the config argument is guaranteed to be of type
AxiosRequestConfig.

The config argument is optional.
*/
const myFirstCreator: Creator<GetRequestArgs, Promise<FirstReturnType>> = function (config){
    return (axios) => {
        return axios.get("https://myurl.com/path", config).then(()=> {
            // Note how we are essentially returning an object of type FirstReturnType
            return {value: 'val'};
        });
    }
}

/*
Second Creator example that has a return type of Promise<SecondReturnType>. Note how the Arguments definition
is now of type DataRequestArgs<string>. This means that the data argument must be a string. The config argument
must be of type AxiosRequestConfig. Again, we do not have to provide typing information within the arguments list
because the typing information is derived from DataRequestArgs<string>.

The config argument is optional.
*/
const mySecondCreator: Creator<DataRequestArgs<string>, Promise<SecondReturnType>> = function (data, config){
    return (axios) => {
        return axios.post("https://myurl.com/path", data, config).then(()=> {
            return {value: 'val', errorCode: 1004};
        });
    }
}

/*
Third Creator example that has a return type of Promise<string>. The Arguments typing in this case
is provided by CustomArgs<string>. This means that the customArg argument is of type string and otherArg
is a number. The data argument is of type string, and config is still of type AxiosRequestConfig.

The config argument is optional.
*/
const myThirdCreator: Creator<CustomArgs<string>, Promise<string>> = function (customArg, otherArg, data, config){
    
    // do something with customArg and otherArg here
    
    return (axios) => {
        return axios.post("https://myurl.com/path", data, config).then(()=> {
            return "string";
        });
    }
}
```

Our original mapping that contains our original Creators:

```
// An object containing our creators.
let creators = {
    myFirstCreator, mySecondCreator, myThirdCreator
};
```

Sample usage and results:

```
// transform our creators (apply a default axios instance to them).
let myClient = prepCreators(creators);

/*
Call examples (note how the config argument is optional).
*/

// retVal is a Promise<FirstReturnType>. 'value' is of type FirstReturnType
const retVal = myClient.myFirstCreator().then((value) => value);

// retVal2 is a Promise<SecondReturnType>. 'value' is of type SecondReturnType
const retVal2 = myClient.mySecondCreator('string data').then((value) => value);

// retVal3 is a Promise<string>. 'value' is of type string
const retVal3 = myClient.myThirdCreator('customArg', 5, 'dataArg').then((value)=> value);
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thank you very much!